# CN1 Connectivity - Concerns when internet is unstable in Public places

Tags: android, ios, connection, codenameone

I'm using Connectivity library to see the internet(Wifi or network data) is active and saving the data in Storage if there is no connectivity(Offline) and synchronize with server when connected to internet. I'm having issues in public places where the internet is consistently unstable(esp. in basements, offices, stores, Coffee shops etc., where there is internet connects in and out). When I check the Connectivity is active but by the time I started synchronizing internet goes offline (Something like this). this leads inconsistent /partial updates to the server. Also, in coffee shops and Airports where wifi gets connected but there will be "Agree Terms and Conditions" page to connect. Not all the browsers will take you to that page directly after joining the Wifi. In that case I see the wifi is active in Mobile but actually it is not activated until I accept the terms and Conditions in IE or some specific browser. Any one else having difficulty in handling these kind of issue from Mobile App?

My App - Hangs on Login screen if I'm trying to login when there is in-stable/in consistent internet.It thinks wifi is there but not.
IF I'm on a screen where I will display list, screen will show blank for infinite time. Adding timeout for server request/response or something will help such scenario.

I know I'm not handling this case in code to show some kind of error message but I need some guidance to detect these conditions suing CN1 API to handle through my app.Please advise.

[image]

Code:

```
  public boolean isOffline() {
        if (Connectivity.isConnected() && forceOffline) {
            relogin();
        }
        return forceOffline || !Connectivity.isConnected();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's impossible to detect online/offline properly as you might be connected to a local wifi/network but it might be a bad connection that won't let you reach the server. As far as the library is concerned you are connected... But in reality you don't have a connection.

First set the timeout values in `NetworkManager` to lower values to improve the experience although this won't solve a situation where data starts downloading and stops in the middle.

Next you need to handle these cases one by one and provide the user with a way to toggle the offline mode. Unfortunately there is no silver bullet for network reliability. You just need to go through every path and try to detect these things.